# Impossible to test a React Component with jest due to a call to axios

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme, create-react-app

i work with a create react app. 
I know it's not a good practice to make an asynchronous call to a web api when testing a component but i want to do that to check all the data returned by the api are correct. I don't want to mock the call.
I test with jest and enzyme but i can't succeed to call the api with axios. I guess it's due to the context of test but i don't know how to set things to have access to xmlhttrequest in test mode.
This is my test :

```
it('renders 10 results', (done) => {
  const wrapper = mount(<UserSearchBox />);

  const input = wrapper.find('.input-search');

  input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'julien'} });


  setTimeout(async ()=>{
     await wrapper.update();
     console.log(wrapper.debug())
     expect(wrapper.find('.results-search').find('ul').children()).toHaveLength(10);
     done();
  },1000);
```

Comment: You really need to be able to justify why you want to not mock the call (not even to the point where you're returning a real but pre-recorded result) in a unit test. Like, do you really want your build fail when your webservice isn't available?

Comment: I agree with you @biziclop. It seems to be weird. In fact, i try to test an autocomplete and we want to verify the structure of data returned by the web api. The data structure can change in the future. I know it's not a unit test...it's more an integration test but it's more relevant for us. If i mock the call, the component is so simple that i don't need to test it.

Comment: I don't know, off the top of my head I could think of 3 different tests that are worth doing: mock API returns correct structure, mock API returns incorrect structure, mock API fails completely (i.e. simulated server error). Of course it's worth doing integration tests too, but you'd probably want to do that by initialising the entire app, so all your external calls work. (Even then, you'd probably want a dummy server for your external calls but that's a different story.)

Comment: Thanks for your help @biziclop. I understand but it doesn't answer to my question. I just want to make an asynchronous call with jest and axios in a react app...

Comment: You'll probably need to wrap your async call (in this case your `input.simulate()`) into an `act()` then.

Comment: What's the error? You can call the real API when running the test.

Comment: @slideshowp2, i can await a call with a mock, i agree with you but when i call await axios.get there is no answer because the test carries on without waiting for the answer of axios. I've used await, call etc...but nothing seems to work.